# Can this get to the end of the function and not return anything?

Tags: c++

I am making a c++ text based game and while making a feature for eating food I made this function names eating. I am getting a warning saying its possible to reach the end with no return value. How is it possible to get to the end and not return something?

```
int inventory::eat(std::string eating)
{
  if (!consumables.empty())
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); i++)
    {
      if (consumables[i].name == eating)
      {
        return consumables[i].effect;
      }
      else
      {
        return 404;
      }
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    return 505;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Not true, but you can get rid of the warning by replacing that last else statement with just `return 505`.

Comment: It's not, but the compiler can't prove it.

Comment: @erip: Well, we don't know the type of `consumables` so it could be an excitingly broken container.

Comment: Note, by the way, that your loop not correct. It will return 404 if the first element has the wrong name, not if it can't find anything with the right name (which is presumably what you wanted).

Comment: Consumables is a vector of structs, eating and name are both strings. Inventory is a class. @BillLynch

Answer (score 5):

Presumably the compiler is unable to tell that if `consumables.empty() == false`, then `consumables.size() > 0`.

I'd probably rewrite it as this, but I'm worried about the if/else inside your for loop.

```
int inventory::eat(std::string eating) {
  for (int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); i++) {
    if (consumables[i].name == eating) {
      return consumables[i].effect;
    } else {
      return 404;
    }
  }
  return 505;
}
```

Comment: If thats the case than is there any way to fix this? Also when i run it and test it i am able to get it to return 505... so its some how able to recognize that it is false.

Comment: @Fatherboard28 The compiler sees a call to a function (`empty`), then a for loop with `i < size()`.  The compiler will see that if `size()` returns 0, the for loop body will never be executed and so the function will exit without returning a value.  This won't normally happen at runtime, but you can clear the warning by replacing `else { return 505; }` with just `return 505;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other thread modifies `consumables` while `eat()` is running, then no, `return` will not be skipped. But the compiler doesn't know that. It doesn't knower that `!empty()` and `size() > 0` mean the same thing for a container. They are just two separate method calls.

That said, I would suggest writing the code more like this, which is easier to read, and avoids the warning:

```cpp
int inventory::eat(const std::string &eating)
{
    if (consumables.empty())
        return 505;

    for (int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (consumables[i].name == eating)
            return consumables[i].effect;
    }

    return 404;
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 and `consumables` supports iterators:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int inventory::eat(const std::string &eating)
{
    if (consumables.empty())
        return 505;

    auto found = std::find_if(
        consumables.begin(), consumables.end(),
        // replace 'consumable' below with your actual type name as needed...
        [&](const consumable &c){ return c.name == eating; }
    );

    if (found != consumables.end())
        return found->effect;

    return 404;
}
```